# Statusbar is transparent while navigationbar is not

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, navigationbar

I'm developing an iOS app with a table view. The navigationbar in the app has an gradient image as a background.

However, as you can see from the picture, while the navigationbar itself is opaque, the statusbar is semi transparent. The content of the tableview is shown through the statusbar when scrolling, while the navigationbar itself is opaque.

I've tried to set the Translucent-property of the navigationbar to false. This makes the statusbar opaque, but it messes up my constraints, so I cannot use it.

Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: NOT a duplicate, but I managed to solve it by turning some of the properties on and off in IB. This is propably a bug in Xcode. It is all transparent now :)

Comment: @kajac If you remember, could you please add your solution as an answer here? Future visitors may have the same issue as you did, and it'd be great if we had an answer here for them.

Comment: @Rob Unfortuanitly I do not remember exactly what I did. I just changed some toggles and properties in Interface Builder and then changed them back to their original state, and it started working just fine. I guess it was a bug in Interface builder or XCode. I'm sorry I cannot help any further.